# Understanding objects relationship in python (confusion)

Tags: python, oop

I am a little bit confused by this example:

```
>>> class A:
...     foo = []
>>> a, b = A(), A()
>>> a
<__main__.A instance at 0x0000000002296A88>
>>> b
<__main__.A instance at 0x0000000002296F88>
>>> a.foo.append(5)
>>> a.foo
[5]
>>> b.foo
[5]
```

1) How does python connect two different instances?

2) Does the instance refer to a class `A()` or `foo` attribute after appending the value?

But when i add `__init__` method, things look different:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.foo = []
...
>>> a, b = A(), A()
>>> a
<__main__.A instance at 0x00000000021EC508>
>>> b
<__main__.A instance at 0x0000000002296F88>
>>> a.foo.append(5)
>>> a.foo
[5]
>>> b.foo
[]
```

3) What is the magic of `__init__` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, `foo` is a *class* attribute, not an *instance* attribute. This means it's shared across all the instances of `A`, which you can check with:

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
print a1.foo is a2.foo
print a1.foo is A.foo
```

In your second example, however, `self.foo = []` makes `foo` an *instance* attribute, built independently for each instance of `A`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the `foo = []` is done at *class definition* time, and thus a single list is associated with the *class*, rather than the instance.

In the second case, the `self.foo = []` is done at *instance initialization* time (which is what `__init__` is - instance initialization), and thus a separate list is associated with each instance.